# Whatsapp Business Api calls for testing the enivronment

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

I am setting up whatsapp business api developer setup following this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/dev-single-instance
I have done everything as mentioned. Using the latest version of Whatsapp api i.e. `v2.23.4`
The docker containers are also running and I can see the login page of whatsapp business at `https://localhost:9090` but the moment I try to check the health mentioned in the above link i.e `https//localhost:9090/v1/health` it gives me an error stating URL NOT FOUND like below
`{"meta":{"version":"v2.23.4","api_status":"stable"},"errors":[{"code":1006,"title":"Resource not found","details":"URL path not found"}]}`
What am I doing wrong here? I also have tried this with `https://localhost:9090/v2/health` but still same error.

Comment: Take a look at the following page and use the examples for /v1/health - https://github.com/fbsamples/WhatsApp-Business-API-Postman-Collection

Answer (score 0):

If user with wa-id exists, but you did not check it, you still can not send him messages. So, you have to get wa_id first - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/contacts

If response status of user in field status is "valid", you can use his wa-id.

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to fire check-contact endpoint then when you get valid `status` copy `wa_id` and you will be able to send messages.